# FFMpeg: "Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required"

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to adapt this FFmpeg script that encodes all video files in a directory, to instead convert mp3 files present in that directory with similar preferences.

### The original script:

*This works for .MOV -> .MOV encoding.*

```
cd /Convert; for i in *.MOV; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -preset veryslow -crf 23 -af "volume=25dB, highpass=f=180, lowpass=f=15000, equalizer=f=50:width_type=h:width=100:g=-15" -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k "${i%.MOV}-ENCODED.MOV"; done
```

### Adapted for mp3 re-encoding:

```
cd /Convert; for i in *.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -af "volume=25dB, highpass=f=180, lowpass=f=15000, equalizer=f=50:width_type=h:width=100:g=-15" -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k "${i%.mp3}-ENCODED.mp3"; done
```

*Throws errors:*

```
Invalid audio stream. Exactly one MP3 audio stream is required.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument.
```

What is wrong with the script?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're trying to store an AAC stream in a MP3 container, would be my guess.

Either store the result as `"${i%.mp3}-ENCODED.aac"` or switch `-c:a aac` to `-c:a libmp3lame`

Comment: Thanks! Funny, I always thought the mp3 format could contain aac. Looks like that presumtion was completely wrong!